html2canvas recorta la imagen en la esquina superior izquierda
Tengo un mapa en mi HTML y estoy usando html2canvas para transformarlo en una imagen para imprimir.
Este es el mapa en mi HTML cuando cargo mi página:

Esta es la imagen que genero

usando este código
var map = document.getElementById('FirstMap_CongestionDetail');

html2canvas(map, { scale: 0.5 }).then(canvas => {
   var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
   // Más código abajo
});

Parece que está recortada en la esquina superior izquierda. No está oculta (ya revisé el padding, margin y overflow hidden).
Este es el código HTML que genera la imagen original:
<div class="leafletMainMap spainCommunities leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim" id="FirstMap_CongestionDetail" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; height: 553px;">

Revisé las clases dentro del archivo CSS y ninguna parece ser el problema.
He visto problemas con html2canvas relacionados con el contenido que se corta cuando se intenta convertir todo el HTML y generalmente se resuelven eliminando el scroll.
Ya intenté lo siguiente pero no funcionó:
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1438#issuecomment-739244530
También intenté modificar la altura y anchura manualmente pero solo hace que la imagen sea más grande o más pequeña. Todavía está recortada.
¿Alguna idea de por qué se corta la imagen?

Tu pregunta debe incluir un [MCVE] que muestre claramente el problema que describes

Leyendo la documentación (que para algo está) vi que se puede desplazar el contenido utilizando los parámetros x e y. En mi caso lo he resuelto tal que así:
function getParams() {
    if(document.querySelector('.spainCommunities')) {
        return { width: 680, height: 500, x: -130, y: -60 };
    } 
    return { width: 420, height: 420, x: -92, y: -88 };
}

De momento tengo solo dos casos y lo he dejado así. ¡Funciona sin problemas!

Puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada si es que tu mismo encontraste la respuesta.

Lo intenté, pero tenía que esperar 14 horas para marcarla como aceptada
